# How to run TestClass several time with different parameters?

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to solve one problem that I have in my PyTest. I am trying to create PyTest that will run one TestClass several times with different parameters. I know that I can use `@pytest.mark.parametrize`, but there is a problem with the test order.

When I use `@pytest.mark.parametrize` so the order of test is:

- Test1[Param1]
- Test1[Param2]
- Test2[Param1]
- Test2[Param2]

I am looking for some solution that will run the test in this order:

- Test1[Param1]
- Test2[Param1]
- Test1[Param2]
- Test2[Param2]

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Why does the order matter? Tests should be isolated so that they can be run in *any* order.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the order of test-data supplied to parametrize should not matter. So, if you are at this point where this is what you need: i.e. order things are executed is important, then your test should explicitly state that. For example

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("data_1, data_2", [
   (...),
   (...)
])
def my_test(data_1, data_2):
    """
    Explain what test is about.
    """
    # Step 1 - Do something first with data_1:
    ...
    # Step 2 - Do something next with data_2:
    ...
```